# Trouble Understanding Powershell Workflow ForEach

Tags: powershell, powershell-workflow

I'm trying to get my feet wet with Powershell Workflows and some work I need to do in parallel.

I didn't get very far before hitting my first roadblock, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here:

```
$operations = ,("Item0", "Item1")

ForEach ($operation in $operations) {
    Write-Output "Item0: $($operation.Item(0)) Item1: $($operation.Item(1))"
}

workflow operationsWorkflow{
    Write-Output "Running Workflow"
    $operations = ,("Item0", "Item1")
    ForEach -Parallel ($operation in  $operations) {
        #Fails: Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'Item'.
        #Write-Output "Item0: $($operation.Item(0)) Item1: $($operation.Item(1))"

        Write-Output "Item $operation"
    }
}

operationsWorkflow
```

Comment: So far, all i can tell is that in this case, the comma-trick isn't working to make an array. My first guess would be to use a .NET `[System.Collections.Generic.List[string[]]]` or something similar instead of relying on powershell array magic.

Comment: Note: even the commented line works if `$operations` has more than one array item added. example: `$operations = @(("Item0", "Item1"), ("ItemA", "ItemB"))`

Comment: I want to like powershell, i'm just always confused by it...

Comment: Thanks Eris, I didn't yet check that more than one element would work, I just got stuck at the first step. So at least I can continue with what I was doing, while we wait for an answer.

Comment: I actually recommend filing an issue on Connect about this. Not sure if it's parallel specific, or workflow-specific though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, thanks to [this excellent article on powershell arrays](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2007/01/23/array-literals-in-powershell/)

> Now, since it’s already an array, casting it again doesn’t result in a
>   second level of nesting:
>
> PS (66) > $a = [array] [array] 1
>
> PS (67) > $a[0]
>
> 1
>
> However using 2 commas *does* nest the array since it is the array
>   construction operation:
>
> PS (68) > $a = ,,1
>
> PS (69) > $a[0][0]
>
> 1

Given that, this works fine:

```
workflow operationsWorkflow{
    Write-Output "Running Workflow"
    $operations = ,,("Item0", "Item1")
    ForEach -Parallel ($operation in  $operations) {
            Write-Output "Item0: $($operation.Item(0)) Item1: $($operation.Item(1))"
    }
}

operationsWorkflow
```

However, if the second comma is added outside the workflow, then errors occur there. So this is a `workflow` or `parallel` specific issue and workaround.